# Obtain Status Code and Response Body from Curl Request

Tags: bash, shell, curl

I want to check http repsonse codes from `curl` yet still be able to retrieve the returned data and store it in a variable.

I found this answer very helpful: https://superuser.com/a/862395/148175
The user describes how he created a new filedescriptor `3` that redirects to `STDOUT` .

Then he ran `curl` in a subshell where he captured the output of `-w "%{http_code}"` into a variable `HTTP_STATUS` and the output to the STDOUT with `-o >(cat >&3)`.

My problem is that I want to capture the output of the STDOUT into a variable after I run curl within a function.

This is my script:

```
#!/bin/bash

exec 3>&1

function curlBinData {
    HTTP_STATUS=$(curl -s -w "%{http_code}" -o >(cat >&3) https://www.google.com --data-binary $1)
    if [ $HTTP_STATUS -ne 200 ]; then
        echo Error: HTTP repsonse is $HTTP_STATUS
        exit
    fi
}

responsedata=$(curlBinData '{"head":5}')
echo $responsedata
```

**What it does:**

The output of curl is directed to `STDOUT`and printed in the console window.

**What's desired**

Since the function calling `curl` is run in a subshell, it should direct the output to the variable `responsedata`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From what I understand, you want this function to output `Error: HTTP repsonse is $status` if `$status` is not equal to `200` and otherwise output the response body, so here is the code for that. I did not see a need for an additional file descriptor, so I removed it.

```
#!/bin/bash
function curlBinData {
    local res=$(curl -s -w "%{http_code}" https://www.google.com --data-binary $1)
    local body=${res::-3}
    local status=$(printf "%s" "$res" | tail -c 3)
    if [ "$status" -ne "200" ]; then
        echo "Error: HTTP repsonse is $status"
        exit
    fi
    echo $body
}

responsedata=$(curlBinData '{"head":5}')
echo $responsedata
```

**Edit:** Simplified the evaluation of the status code from the curl response to just get the last three characters a.k.a. the status code.

Comment: Awesome, thank you! Couldn't you just use a regular expression that takes the last three characters and interprets it as status code? Or is it not guaranteed to be a three digit code?

Comment: Yeah, it would probably have been simpler to just pull the last three characters.

Comment: I simplified he evaluation of the status code to just get the last three characters.

Comment: I had to change it to `body=${res::-3}` otherwise it would cut off mone character too many.

Comment: I don't know what I was thinking. I don't think I checked the removal of the last three characters before I sent it to you. I fixed the answers to have `${res::-3}`

Comment: I got the HTTP status cut by one digit, I fixed it in this way:

 `local status=$(echo $res | tail -c 4)`

Comment: getting two errors line 4=> -3: substring expression < 0 and line 6=> [: : integer expression expected. Any help?

Comment: Shouldn't the error be written to stderr so it's not consumed but the caller of the function?

Comment: Instead of `printf | tail -c3` to get the statuscode just use `${res: -3}` -- note the space is required to avoid confusing the bash substring syntax with the POSIX parameter-default syntax. OTOH `printf %s "$body"` is [better (safer) than `echo`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/65803/why-is-printf-better-than-echo)